# Converting LPCTSTR to LPWSTR

Tags: visual-c++, unicode, mfc

using MFC and Unicode-Build

i want to change the colum-header-text of a listctrl and to do so i have to convert an LPCTSTR to an LPWSTR. what i do now is

```
void CSPCListViewCtrl::SetHeaderText(long lCol, LPCTSTR lColText)
{
    CListCtrl& ListCtrl = GetListCtrl();

    LV_COLUMN lvc;
    ::ZeroMemory((void *)&lvc, sizeof(LVCOLUMN));
    lvc.mask |= LVCF_TEXT;

    ListCtrl.GetColumn(lCol, &lvc);
    lvc.pszText = const_cast<LPWSTR>(lColText);

    ListCtrl.SetColumn(lCol, &lvc);
}
```

it seems to work but the const_cast looks somewhat strange and wrong to me so i tried out something like

```
USES_CONVERSION;
lvc.pszText = CT2W(lColText);
```

this seems to work in release-build but produces garbage in debug-build so i wonder what is the correct way to do it?

Comment: There is no `LPWSTR` in `LV_COLUMN` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774760(v=vs.85).aspx). I assume the string passed by the LPTSTR argument is somehow temporary. You should consider the ownership and lifetime of the string that you pass to the pszText member.

Comment: ok, my mistake. LV_COLUMN::pszText is a LPTSTR (wich compiles to an LPWSTR in my unicode-case). so you mean just const_casting to LPTSTR is the correct way? yes, the passed argument is temporary but i think SetColumn makes a copy, isn't it?

Comment: Although `const_cast` may work in all existing versions of list control, it most certainly doesn't have to. Imagine that in the next release they will enhance the column titles to have to parts, left- and right-aligned, and choose to use something like `strtok()` to parse the `pszText`. This may cause access violation if your string was in fact constant. Bottom line is - you have to create a non-constant copy of that text; one way is suggested in the answer below.

Comment: @VladFeinstein: That's not correct. The fact that *pszText* is declared non-const is an artifact. The `LV_COLUMN` structure is used both to set and read column information. When reading, the pointer must point to a non-const buffer; when writing, it designates a pointer to a constant. C has no provisioning to modify the const-ness of a struct member depending on whether it is used as an in or out parameter. The `const_cast` is in fact safe, and can be used (with an appropriate comment). Microsoft isn't going to change the behavior of an API in a way that would break 98% of software out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[TL;DR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TL;DR): Using `const_cast<LPTSTR>(lColText)` is safe when calling [CListCtrl::SetColumn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b11bety8.aspx).

But why then is the *pszText* member of the [LVCOLUMN structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774743.aspx) declared non-const? The `LVCOLUMN` structure is used both to set and retrieve information. When retrieving a column's text, you need to pass in a modifiable buffer (and length argument). When setting a columns text, on the other hand, the system uses the *pszText* member and internally stores a copy. It does not attempt to write to it. This is [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774743.aspx) as well, even if very subtly:

> *cchTextMax*
>   Size in *TCHAR*s of the buffer pointed to by the *pszText* member. **If the structure is not receiving information about a column, this member is ignored.**

This is a common pattern in the Windows API, where the same structure is used both as an input and output parameter. The only option to work around this would have been to introduce a `const`-ified version for those structures. When the Windows API was invented 30 years ago, this wasn't deemed necessary or useful. Besides, it would have made a common pattern (read-update-write) more tedious and error prone, as the data would have to be manually copied between unrelated types.

---

Now that you know, that using a `const_cast` is safe in the scenario you described, you may be wondering, if it is a good idea to use it. That depends on a number of factors, e.g.

- Can you come up with a helpful comment to concisely explain, why this is ok? Something along the lines of `// Totally safe, it's just that M$ sucks` probably won't cut it.
- Will all members on your team understand the implications, or will this present a red herring in heap corruption debug sessions?
- Do you have coding guidelines that allow the use of `const_cast`s?
- Are you using static code analysis tools that won't produce false positives for `const_cast`s?

If you find that you cannot satisfactorily answer all those questions, you may consider implementing (technically unnecessary) manual copying (and exchange a `const_cast` for exception handling):

```
void CSPCListViewCtrl::SetHeaderText(long lCol, LPCTSTR lColText) {
    CListCtrl& ListCtrl = GetListCtrl();

    LVCOLUMN lvc = {0};
    lvc.mask |= LVCF_TEXT;

    // Create modifiable copy of lColText
    size_t colTextLength = _tcslen(lColText);
    std::vector<TCHAR> buffer(colTextLength + 1);
    std::copy(lColText, lColText + colTextLength + 1, buffer.data());
    lvc.pszText = buffer.data();

    ListCtrl.SetColumn(lCol, &lvc);
}
```

---

One more note on your use of character string encodings: You are mixing the use of [Generic-Text Mappings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c426s321.aspx) with explicit Unicode (UTF-16LE) encoding. To add consistency, you should change the *lColText* argument to type `LPCWSTR`, and use an `LVCOLUMNW` structure (as well as a `const_cast<LPWSTR>` if you decide to go that route). Unfortunately, when using MFC, you will have to resort to using the generic-text mappings when calling any class members. But at least you will get a compiler error in case of mismatching character encodings.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CString::GetBuffer()`

```
void SetHeaderText(long lCol, LPCTSTR lColText)
{
    LV_COLUMN lvc;
    ::ZeroMemory((void *)&lvc, sizeof(LVCOLUMN));
    lvc.mask |= LVCF_TEXT;

    list.GetColumn(lCol, &lvc);

    CString str = lColText;
    lvc.pszText = str.GetBuffer();

    list.SetColumn(lCol, &lvc);

    str.ReleaseBuffer();
    //ReleaseBuffer is option in this case because 
    //"str" is local variable and is destroyed before being used again*
}


SetHeaderText(0, L"text");
```

In UNICODE, `LPTSTR` is just `LPWSTR` (or simply `wchar_t*`)

If for some reason you have ANSI text, then you can use `CString` for conversion

```
CStringA ansi = "Text";
CStringW wide = CStringW(ansi);

SetHeaderText(0, wide);
```

See also
[CString::GetBuffer()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa314880%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

Comment: Regarding your code comment: Isn't `str` destroyed *after* being used?

Comment: @harper I meant to say before being used "again", I don't know how to explain that properly, I should have just left it alone. I added link to documentation.